# Change the execution order in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I have the below code

```
function run(){
    one();
    two();
    three();
}

function one(){
    console.log(1);
}

function two(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        console.log(2);
    });
}

function three(){
    console.log(3);
}

run();
```

The Output of the following code will be `1,3,2`

What are the changes we have to do in a code so that output will be `1,2,3` ?

Comment: Removing the `setTimeout` in `two`, since it's asynchronous? It's hard to know why you are asking that. Could you give more context?

Comment: indentation and linespacing is terrible, and styling is inconsistent...

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

```
async function run() {
    await one();
    await two()
    await three()
}


function one() {
    Promise.resolve(
        console.log(1)
    )
}

function two() {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log(2);
            resolve();
        });
    });


}

function three() {
    Promise.resolve(
        console.log(3)
    )
}

run();
```

Answer (score 2):

Realise that `three` is called immediately after `two`. If you want `three` to only be called once the `setTimeout` inside `two` expires, then you should call `three` in *that* `setTimeout` callback.

To achieve that, you can pass an argument to `two`:

```js
function run() {
  one();
  two(three); // Tell "two" what to call when its timer expires
}

function one() {
  console.log(1);
}

function two(callback) { // <-- callback argument
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log(2);
    callback(); // <---
  })
}

function three() {
  console.log(3);
}

run();
```

### Promises

Once you start using `setTimeout` to chain several asynchronous pieces of code, you will soon get into what is a "callback hell".

So for completeness, here is an implementation using the modern `async/await` syntax for using promises:

```js
// Generic helper function
const delay = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

async function run() {
  one();
  await two();
  three();
}

function one() {
  console.log(1);
}

async function two() {
  await delay(0); // So to have the timeout involved...
  console.log(2);
}

function three() {
  console.log(3);
}

run();
```

Comment: Nice!
87654321 - for comment length... :)

Answer (score 1):

you can use promise

```
function run(){
one();
two().then(three)

}


function one(){
console.log(1);
}

function two(){
  return new Promise((resolve , reject) => {
    setTimeout(function(){
    console.log(2);
    resolve()
    })
  })

}



function three(){

console.log(3);
}

run();
```

Comment: I don't want to mark your answer as not useful, but introducing promises is complicating the issue.

Comment: @iAmOren On the contrary, promises are the standard measure to solve this problem, so any answer that does not mention them would be incomplete.

Comment: To clarify myself: "promises" can be an answer - hence, me not negatively marking your answer.  That said, "standard" is subjective...

Comment: There should be one answer using `await` in conjunction with promises for this to be a _complete_ q&a.

Answer (score 1):

```
   function run() {
      one();
      two(); 
    }

    function one() {
      console.log(1);
    }

    function two() { 
      setTimeout(function() {
        console.log(2);
         three()
      })
    }

    function three() {
      console.log(3);
    }

    run();
```